# Find the first bar within the current week

Tags: pine-script

Trying to create an expression for the first daily bar within the current week.  The first bar within the weekly set of candles should be correct but what I have so far is not correct.

Note I cannot use the built in date functions specified here https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#time-dates-and-sessions

```
thisweek = security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", barstate.islast, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
firstday = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", barstate.isfirst, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)


is_monday = thisweek and firstday
```

Comment: Care to explain why you can't use Pine's time functions?

Comment: Because of exchange and timezone differences, using the monday built in function doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
is_newbar(res) =>
    t = time(res)
    change(t) != 0 ? 1 : 0


firstcandle=is_newbar("D") and is_newbar("W")

var countD = 0
countD := is_newbar("W") ? 1 : is_newbar("D") ? countD + 1 : countD

is_monday = countD==1
```